# Command line Data Loader for scheduled import of parent and child records

Tags: force.com, data-loader, commandline

I am struggling with an urgent issue related to periodically scheduling data import using Dataloder CLI.
We are planning to use command line DataLoader for scheduling the data load for multiple related objects which will reside in the FTP folder. We will be having a separate file for each object and an external id for each record in each file. For example, 1 file for Account, 1 for contact, and so on.

Can you please provide me pointers on how to achieve the below requirements using Dataloder CLI?

1. Importing Account and Contact records: We need to import Account records first and then Contact records. How to identify if Account import is successful and only when account import is successful then import the related contacts? That is how to define the sequence of import based on the success or failure of parent records?
2. How to clean the FTP folder when the import is successful so that it won't pick the same file again? This will be a daily activity and hence we need to remove the files every day without any manual intervention.
3. How to notify the users in case of failure from the command line data loader(we are preferring sending an email to an alias in case of failure so that they can then manually correct the file and place it again in the FTP folder)?

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Since you have external IDs you should not see any duplicate record creation even if you re-process a file previously processed.

Comment: @PhilW, Thanks for the response. But this will be a daily activity and hence we need to remove the files every day without any manual intervention. Updated this point in the question as well

Comment: An option to handle the daily activity is to use a sub-folder based on the date; e.g. 20200423, and only consider the content of the folder for today's date.